# SugarSS throwing unecessary `CssSyntaxError`

Tags: sass, stylelint

I have defined a `mixin` for adding styles to an element. This compiles perfectly but is throwing an error when I run `stylelint` over it.
My `stylelint` configuration is as follows:

```
{
    "plugins": [
      "stylelint-scss"
    ],
    "extends": "stylelint-config-sass-guidelines",
    "rules": {
      "block-opening-brace-space-before": "never",
      "color-hex-length": "long",
      "declaration-block-trailing-semicolon": "never",
      "indentation": 2,
      "max-nesting-depth": 2,
      "scss/dollar-variable-pattern": "[a-zA-Z0-9]+",
      "selector-combinator-space-after": "always",
      "selector-combinator-space-before": "always",
      "selector-list-comma-newline-after": "never-multi-line"
    }
  }
```

[image]

**EDIT**
[image]

Getting this error without `--custom-syntax sugarss`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CssSyntaxError is thrown because the [SugarSS syntax](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sugarss#syntax) does not support interpolation, i.e. `#{element}`.

You can either:

- write in Sass
- write in SugarSS and use Sass-like [PostCSS plugins](https://www.postcss.parts/tag/sass)

It's not possible to do both.

---

stylelint supports Sass, SCSS and SugarSS out-of-the-box. You don't need to use the `--custom-syntax` flag.

If you want to continue to write in Sass, you should remove the `--custom-syntax sugarss` flag from your stylelint command (and quote your glob), like so:

```
stylelint "**/*.{sass,scss}" --fix
```

If you want to write in SugarSS and use Sass-like PostCSS plugins, you should:

- change your file extensions to `.sss`
- remove the `--custom-syntax sugarss` flag from your stylelint command (and quote your glob): `stylelint "**/*.sss" --fix`
- install the [postcss-mixins](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-mixins) plugin
- change your code to match the compatible syntax:

```
@define-mixin set-link-style $element
    $(element)
        text-decoration: none
        ..

@mixin set-link-style a
```

Comment: Thank you for such an elaborate answer. I would want to go with the first option and I did try to remove `--custom-syntax sugarss` but now I have a different error. I will post the screenshot in the question.

Comment: It looks like the Sass parser isn't compatible with the new `@use` module syntax. You should open an issue in the stylelint tracker (https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/issues/new?template=REPORT_A_BUG.md).